# forfiles modified files excluding newly created

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I am trying to write code that will allow me to identify files in a folder that have been modified since the beginning of the month, but that are not newly created (signifying a revision change).  Outputting the number of changed files is more important than the name of the modified files, but it can be either.

I have tried to use forfiles to achieve this, but am unable to figure out how to do this without it also listing newly created files.

I have thought that maybe searching for files created before the beginning of the month yet modified within the last month might be the answer, but am unsure how to do this.  My code so far still shows newly created files.

```
@echo off
REM set revisions folder path


 set revisions="C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\\"
 forfiles /P %revisions% /S /D +08/01/2019 > "Revisions last 30days.txt"
```

Comment: Your question appears to be a little unclear to me. Are you trying to list, count, _(or both)_, files which were modified this month, and have an earlier creation date and time? I will also let you know that `ForFiles` works only with `Modified`, so using it alone will not achieve your goal!

Comment: I am sorry, I will try to clarify.

I am trying to find the number of files in a folder that have been revised in the last month.  This number cannot include newly created files, it needs to only be the count of revised programs.  I am trying to find a creative way to do this.

I then also will need to find all newly created files within the last month ignoring the revised files.


So yes files which were modified this month, & have an earlier creation date and time, forfiles will not work?

Comment: I'll mention that the created stamp is not necessarily the date  when the file was first made. Additionally it's important to note that StackOverflow is supposed to be for assistance in fixing a specific issue with your code. Until you've created code intended to achieve your task, you'd effectively be requesting someone else to write it for you, and for free. It appears that you're still at the research stage, and as such [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) would be a more appropriate location for your question.

Comment: I do not expect anyone to write my code for me, I guess I am not even sure where to go from here to even continue to write the code myself.  I started with the forfiles because I thought I was on the right path and was unable to get the results desired, that is why I posted here.  I am attempting to write this code myself, but was looking for guidance on what I was doing wrong.

I will check out superuser.

Comment: Once you've settled on a methodology, have written sufficient code to attempt the task and if you're still encountering an issue, please feel free to update your question. Alternatively you could delete the question and submit a new one later, should you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I will make a SWAG and think that you want to identify files written in the current month, but were created earlier than the last time they were written. Is that close?

Place all four (4) files in the same directory. This assumes that if the difference between the creation time and last write time is less than one (1) second, that there has not been a revision.

=== revs.bat

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0revs.ps1"
```

=== revs.ps1

```
$RevDir = 'C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)'
$CloseEnough = New-Timespan -Seconds 1
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $RevDir |
    Where-Object {
        ($_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date (Get-Date) -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)) -and
        (($_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime) -gt $CloseEnough)
    }
```

=== revsnot.bat

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0revsnot.ps1"
```

=== revsnot.ps1

```
$RevDir = 'C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)'
$CloseEnough = New-Timespan -Seconds 1
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $RevDir |
    Where-object {
        ($_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date (Get-Date) -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)) -and
        (($_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime) -lt $CloseEnough)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately when I went to test it, I was confronted with a message telling me that "the execution of scripts is disabled on this system", our IT locks us down hard.

But I am intrigued now to learn powershell, from looking at the code I am unable to decipher most of what you are doing...

Comment: What is the output of the command `powershell -Command "Get-ExecutionPolicy`?See also: https://superuser.com/a/106363/447008

Comment: You can change the execution policy temporarily as part of the [tag:powershell] command options, instead of setting it permanently, if you prefer. e.g. `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0revs.ps1"`

Answer (score 0):

This is going to hurt the eyes of everyone who reads it as it is quite possibly the absolute worst coding on the history of this site, but it works for its purpose, and is the best I can currently do.  I am still learning this stuff, and although this does work, I really would have liked to know how to put my results into variables so I did not have to do it the way I did with .txt files...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set revisions="C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\\"

dir %revisions% /T:C /A-D /O:-D > %revisions%"creation date.txt"
dir %revisions% /T:W /A:-D /O:-D > %revisions%"modified date.txt"

findstr /vig:"C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\creation date.txt" "C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\modified date.txt" > "C:\Users\nlehman\Desktop\New folder (3)\difference.txt"

findstr /b "08/"  difference.txt > "rev changes.txt"
find /v /c "" "rev changes.txt" > revs.txt

del %revisions%"creation date.txt"
del %revisions%"modified date.txt"
del %revisions%"difference.txt"

type "rev changes.txt" "revs.txt" > "revisions.txt"

del %revisions%"rev changes.txt"
del %revisions%"revs.txt"
```